# trouble with custom 403 404 error pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

hy,

I have these lines in my `.htaccess` file.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404.php
```

the problem is, I guess, that the styleshets that are linked inside the 404.php page, load or don't load depending on whether I get the error from a file that is inside a subdirectory or that is in the root directory.

so when I access a file that in lets say

> /include/file.php

then the css usually doesn't load, but if the file is in root like

> /file.php

then it does load.

does anybody have an answer?

Comment: Change the CSS path in your 404.php file to an absolute path from relative one

Comment: How are you linking to the stylesheets on those pages?

Comment: I am linking like this css/style.css but I tried all kinds of variations I don't know though if I tried the absolute path I don't even know what it is :).

Comment: Do you use URL rewrite?